# Archiving 32 million Oracle table rows using a new commit strategy in a PL/SQL loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, locking, commit

I've been asked to modify the below procedure to handle 32 million rows as the current job is running to slow. They told me to commit every 10,000 rows I'm guessing in a bulk loop but by committing every 10,000 I then lose the exclusive lock on the table. I'm looking at an efficient way of processing these records with the exclusive lock on the table.

The job archives old records in a production table called act_plus_triggers into archive table called arc_act_plus_triggers but inserts records into a copy table called act_plus_triggers_copy first before inserting these records into the archive table. Any suggestions? I run on an Oracle 11g database.

```
PROCEDURE archive_act_plus_triggers (p_batch_name IN VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN

  --
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION ENABLE RESUMABLE TIMEOUT 57600 NAME ''ARC ACT+ TRIGGERS''';

  -- lock the table so no updates/deletes/inserts can be made to this table
  LOCK TABLE act_plus_triggers IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;

   -- insert all records from act_plus_triggers into the act_plus_triggers_copy table
   INSERT INTO act_plus_triggers_copy
      SELECT apt.*
        FROM act_plus_triggers apt JOIN works wrk ON wrk.cre_surr_id = apt.wrk_cre_surr_id
       WHERE apt.status NOT IN ('EXT', 'EXP', 'INT')
          OR ( (apt.status = 'INT'
            AND apt.uc_surr_id IS NULL
            AND apt.terminal_date > SYSDATE)
           OR (apt.status = 'INT'
           AND apt.uc_surr_id IS NOT NULL
           AND apt.usage_value > 0))
          OR (apt.status IN ('EXT', 'EXP')
          AND NVL (apt.process_desc, '?') IN ('TRANSACTIONAL', 'AMAZONITUNE')
          AND wrk.extracted_for_nwr_date IS NOT NULL
          AND wrk.logically_deleted_y IS NULL
          AND wrk.ice_wrk_status = '4');

   dbms_output.put_line('  Inserted into Act_plus_triggers_copy : ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);

   -- insert the data in the copy table to the archived data table
   INSERT --+ append
         INTO  arc_act_plus_triggers
      SELECT apt.*
        FROM act_plus_triggers apt
       WHERE NOT EXISTS
                (SELECT 1
                   FROM act_plus_triggers_copy aptc
                  WHERE aptc.surr_id = apt.surr_id)
         AND apt.status IN ('EXT', 'EXP');

   dbms_output.put_line('  Inserted into Arc_act_plus_triggers : '|| SQL%ROWCOUNT);

   -- truncate table deleteing all records in the act_plus_triggers
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE act_plus_triggers';
   dbms_output.put_line('  Act_plus_triggers truncated: '|| SQL%ROWCOUNT);

   -- insert all record from act_plus_triggers_copy into the truncated table act_plus_triggers
   INSERT --+ append
         INTO  act_plus_triggers apt
      SELECT * FROM act_plus_triggers_copy;

   dbms_output.put_line('  Inserted into Act_plus_triggers : '|| SQL%ROWCOUNT);

    -- commit all inserts above
    COMMIT;

    -- truncate the table act_plus_triggers_copy
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE act_plus_triggers_copy';

END archive_act_plus_triggers;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is not too much to do:

- Use PARALLEL hint in SELECT - to read in parallel streams
- Use ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL_DML, to write in parallel streams
- Use APPEND hint in insert to use direct-pah write
- make the intermediate table act_plus_triggers_copy NOLOGGING
- Invalidate indexes on target table (if any)
- Drop constraints on target table (if any)
- Disable triggers in target table (if any)

Usually writing into tables is quite fast, while index maintenance or constrains make the ETL slow.

PS: also check which step is actually slow. Maybe you have problem with the middle step where you use `ANTI-JOIN - NOT EXISTS`. So either the 1st step is slow due to index maintenance (if present), or the 2nd step is slow due to index not being used(if not present). IHMO you should disable indexes on `act_plus_triggers_copy` before 1st step and rebuild them before 2nd step.

*Batch mode and committing after 10000 will not speed it up.*

Comment: I would also suggest turning the second insert into a merge statement; that might enable the db to find a better plan, as it's then effectively doing a left outer join.

Comment: Thanks Marius Catalin Jucan and ibre5041 for the suggestions, I'll start looking at these straight away

Comment: @MariusCatalinJucan That edit should have been a comment.  Otherwise your putting words into the OP's mouth.

Comment: Thanks Boneist, i'll take a look

Comment: @ibre5041  You should probably use ALTER SESSION *ENABLE* PARALLEL DML, as opposed to FORCE. I have seen cases where this can (incorrectly) force recursive SQL execute in parallel.

Comment: @ibre5041 thanks i'll change it ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML